# How do you unit test when an object ID is not set until saved in DB but you have invariants being checked in the creation method?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to unit test with MSTest and here is my scenario:

I am using Entity Framework Core and C#.  I have an entity (Order)  with a child entity (OrderLineItem) where the ID is not created until it is stored in the database (the db creates the ID).

In the unit test, I am creating an instance of the Order class in which the ID has not been created it.  In my command class for creating OrderLineItem there is a property for OrderID.  When I create the Order object in the unit test there is no Order ID yet and so I cant pass it into the command handler without an exception being thrown because I validate that an existing Order exists and try to retrieve it.

I am trying not to have to do database transactions in the unit test but just domain logic. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a mocked DbContext that works like a DbContext use the [in-memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) as mentioned by Peter. It works as advertised for most things and should be your first port of call.

I maintain one of the mocking libraries ([EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing)); IMO you should only consider one of the mocking libraries if you need to do things that the in-memory provider doesn't support like relational operations (FromSql*, ExecuteSql* etc) or some LINQ operations (ElementAt, Indexed Select, SkipWhile etc); Or you want to verify invocations.

Answer (score 1):

During unit testing you should mock your dependencies. In case of database, you have several options:

- Use [EntityFrameworkCore3Mock](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core3-mock), prerequisite is to use **Moq** as your mocking framework
- Use [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore), it has several limitations, like does not support transactions
- Use [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore), it does support transactions, but does not handle complex types

Whenever you are testing functionality which is related to `OrderLineItem` then you can **Arrange** your database to already have an Order there.

Comment: Does EntityFrameworkCore3Mock - does it populate the id like the db transaction would?

Comment: @MikeLenart If you use the `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` annotation then yes it should populate that column. On the other hand this library has also some limitations, please check the [TODO section](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core3-mock#todo)